# How to Create Yum Cache Server for client machines in LAN

Tags: centos, cache, update, packages

Like in Ubuntu we have the option of creating "Ubuntu update cache server" which downloads and update packages directly from internet and serves other client ubuntu machines for installing/updating packages. In the same way for RHEL based distribution (Centos,fedora) can we create "update cache server" which fatches packages from internet and provide to client machine in LAN locally.Also like ubuntu that cache server serves for all version of centos,fedora etc.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods to achieve this.

The simplest option would be to create a caching proxy server such as squid, which clients could be configured to use to connect via.  Once a client downloads one package, the rest of the clients would collect the package from the squid cache, rather than downloading direct from the repository.

The YUM website [lists several options](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumMultipleMachineCaching.html) (including mounting `/var/cache/yum` over shared storage, e.g. NFS, or using `rsync` to copy cached packages to other machines) where a cache is created by synchronising package files from a remote mirror, most of which would require substantial configuration and disk space to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

install and configure [mrepo](https://github.com/dagwieers/mrepo) by Dag Wieers. Works like a charm. It is not like apt-cache of apt-cache-ng, but no such thing exists in yum land that I know of.